# Como faço para o servidor em que hospedei meu site leia meu arquivo HTML?

Tags: php

Eu criei meu site HTML e subi ele para o servidor. No entanto, quando entro com endereço, sou encaminhado primeiramente ao Index of da pasta public.html. Segundo a assistência de hospedagem, o problema deve-se a ausência de um arquivo php que desse a instrução de leitura. A minha dúvida é esta: como eu crio esse php para que ele faça a leitura e disponibilize corretamente o meu site.

Comment: No site HTML que você criou, existe o arquivo index.html no diretório raiz do projeto? Porque na verdade você não precisa necessariamente de um arquivo PHP, apenas do arquivo index que o apache busca e carrega por padrão.

Comment: Vc está usando Wordpress?

Comment: Não, eu mesmo criei

Comment: Tem quanto tempo que o serviço foi habilitado? Vc comfigurou o DNS? Normalmente demora algumas horas até a URL ficar ativa

Comment: Não foi eu que configurei, mas ele está habilitado desde segunda-feira

Comment: qual é o link do site?

Comment: http://www.barbeirocascavel.com.br/

Comment: eu ainda estou construindo ele, mas pus o esboço para já ir identificando possíveis problemas como este

Comment: Continua do mesmo jeito, Hugo. A única coisa que alterou foi as cores dos backgrounds que agora estão corretas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema muito provavelmente é por causa do "camel case", seu index tem o `i` maiúsculo, está `Index.html` e ser for `index.html`, com `i` **minúsculo**, provavelmente vai resolver.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: é isso mesmo, Hugo! Obrigado meu caro. Muito atencioso da sua parte sanar essa dúvida numa sexta à noite, agradeço.

Comment: @RogerLima é que hj minha noiva viajou ai to de bobeira bebendo e estudando haha, valeu a força 